# Twitter API + OAuth - Automatically send status update & follow someone

Tags: oauth, twitter

How would I get a web app (for example, @Example) to do the following for an authenticated user?

1. Send a status update (send a new tweet, ie. "I just used the new @Example app!")
2. Follow @Example

In one click... Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks! ♥

Answer (score 0):

Using the REST API, you could call [statuses/update](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update) with your tweet text, and then (after receiving a 200 response code denoting a successful update) you could call [friendships/create](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/friendships/create) to then follow @Example using the `screen_name` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out::
http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/followers

Answer (score 0):

[REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api)  provides simple interfaces, that perform all integrations with Twitter.
Document describes REST API Resources such as: Timelines, Tweets, Search, Direct Message, Friends & Followers etc.

[Twitter OAuth with .NET](http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2009/03/twitter-oauth-with-net/) describes how to implement Twitter OAuth and send Twitter status
update.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind little $ use [tweetapart.com](http://tweetapart.com) it's the easiest tool I found, it supports auto hashtagging too.

```
http://tweetapart.com/tweet?api_key={API_KEY}&status={YOUR_STATUS}
```

Comment: Please add code to show how you would use it in this case.