# Twitter API + @Anywhere: Automatically send status update & follow someone

Tags: oauth, twitter, twitter-anywhere

How would I get a web app (for example, @Example) to do the following for an authenticated user?

1. Send a status update (send a new tweet, ie. "I just used the new @Example app!")
2. Follow @Example

In one click, using the Twitter API and @Anywhere framework... Can someone point me in the right direction? This is similar to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505990/twitter-api-oauth-automatically-send-status-update-follow-someone), only that one is for OAuth.

Thanks! ♥